# Getting an error trying to convert dict_values to list in ipdb

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.5 I am trying to get the values from a dictionary like so:

```
data_dict.values()
# result: dict_values(['117487614', '117487614', '117487614'])
```

Now if I try to convert this into a list

```
list(data_dict.values())
```

I get an error:

```
*** Error in argument: '(data_dict.values())'
```

These expressions are being executed inside `ipdb`:

```
ipdb> patterns_and_values
{'value_{}.mainContent_root_pwdPin': '85785226', 
'value_{}.mainContent_root_txtBenutzerkennung': '85785226', 
'value_{}.mainContent_root_txtRZBK': '85785226'}

ipdb> patterns_and_values.values()
dict_values(['85785226', '85785226', '85785226'])

ipdb> list(patterns_and_values.values())
*** Error in argument: '(patterns_and_values.values())'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're using the `ipdb` *command* `list` from what I can understand. If `ipdb` follows the interface defined by `pdb` [this doesn't invoke the `list()` function as you'd expect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-list).

Exit the `ipdb` debugger to get this to work correctly or, again if `ipdb` uses the same commands as `ipdb`, use `p list(patterns_and_values.values())` in order to get an expression evaluated inside the debugger.

Comment: @Ugur you're welcome. This is why you need to include the *full* context in the question so people don't assume (like I did) that you're masking the `list` function.

Comment: `!list(data_dict.values())` is another option

Answer (score 2):

Escape your expression with an exclamation mark so ipdb doesn't interpret `list` as a special command:

```
!list(data_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
patterns_and_values = {'value_{}.mainContent_root_pwdPin': '85785226', 'value_{}.mainContent_root_txtBenutzerkennung': '85785226', 'value_{}.mainContent_root_txtRZBK': '85785226'}
only_values = patterns_and_values.values()
value_list = [x for x in only_values]
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! But still I am wondering why I cannot convert using list()

Comment: Glad it helped. There can be some error with ipdb. *I am not sure.*

Answer (score -3):

```
d = {"d":1,"s":1}
print (d.values())
print(list(d.values()))
```

Keep Coding Keep learning

Comment: Though "it works for me" is considered an answer, it doesn't really explain why it doesn't work for the OP.